# How can I type in a progress bar in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

good to see you!

I have a question about bootstrap. So I basically have this progress bar on which I have managed to get to display the current progress in ml and per cent (it's for showing the daily intake of water current/all required). Now I want to display on the right side the amount of ml(per cent) left, as shown in the picture: 20% is done / 80% is left. I hope you get what I want, sorry for my English, I am not native.

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-info active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">800 ml (20%)
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide a little bit more detail here. Maybe post some code? Its pretty clear that you will need to add another html element though and style it accordingly.

Comment: Yes guys, thanks for the responces. Here is my code so far:

                                    <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-info active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">800 ml (20%)
                                </div>
                            </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked well:

Added new style to the css

```
.progress-bar1 {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 20px;
color: #000;
text-align: center;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
-webkit-transition: width .6s ease;
-o-transition: width .6s ease;
transition: width .6s ease;
}
```

Changed html to:

```
 <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-info active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20"
                                 aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">800 ml (20%)
                            </div><p class="progress-bar1 text-center">140</p>
                        </div>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the text in two `span`s, one floated left, one floated right, and [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) the containing progress bar.

Comment: I tried it, although I think I did not clearfixed it correctly. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 30px auto 0;
}

.progress {
  position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f5f5f5), to(#f9f9f9));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#f9f9f9', GradientType=0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.progress .bar {
    width: 0%;
    height: 18px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background-color: #0e90d2;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#149bdf), to(#0480be));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#149bdf', endColorstr='#0480be', GradientType=0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.6s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.6s ease;
    transition: width 0.6s ease;
}

.progress-striped .bar {
    background-color: #62c462;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    -webkit-background-size: 40px 40px;
    -moz-background-size: 40px 40px;
    -o-background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}

.progress.active .bar {
    -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}

.progress-danger .bar {
    background-color: #dd514c;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ee5f5b), to(#c43c35));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ee5f5b', endColorstr='#c43c35', GradientType=0);
}

.progress-danger.progress-striped .bar {
    background-color: #ee5f5b;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}

.progress-success .bar {
    background-color: #5eb95e;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#62c462), to(#57a957));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#62c462', endColorstr='#57a957', GradientType=0);
}

.progress-success.progress-striped .bar {
    background-color: #62c462;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}

.progress-info .bar {
    background-color: #4bb1cf;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#5bc0de), to(#339bb9));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5bc0de', endColorstr='#339bb9', GradientType=0);
}

.progress-info.progress-striped .bar {
    background-color: #5bc0de;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}


.remainder{
  float:right;
  font-size: 12px;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="progress">
<div class="progress progress-info
     progress-striped">
     <span class='remainder'>80%</span>
  <div class="bar"
       style="width: 30%;">800 ml (20%)</div>
</div>

<div class="progress progress-danger
     progress-striped active">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help! It works, although yesterday I found a shorter solution but had some internet issues and could not post it earlier. You can check it out.